Azure Function App Phyton - Accessing Storage Account
I have created a function app on a linux host. I deploy via a pipeline and everythings works as expected. Until I start importing azure libraries, then the functions are just not deployed. No errors.
#When adding below functions fails to show in the azure portal. 
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

FullCode:
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

app = func.FunctionApp()

import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.route(route="get_port_data", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def get_port_data(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    lat = req.params.get('lat')
    long = req.params.get('lng')

    # credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    # blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://xx.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)    

    jsn = {"region":"USAC","port":"West"}

    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(jsn),
        mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
    )

Deployment pipeline:

# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- none

variables:
# Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'xx'

# Web app name
  webAppName: 'xx'

# Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Environment name
  environmentName: 'func-xx'

# Project root folder.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

# Python version: 3.11. Change this to match the Python runtime version running on your web app.
  pythonVersion: '3.11'

  workingDirectory: ''

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    # - bash: |
    #     if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
    #     then
    #         dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
    #     fi
    #   workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    #   displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.11'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.11

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureServiceConnectionId)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'


In Python function when code syntax not correct is does not show in portal even if deployment is correct.
To access file from blob container use below given code.
This code worked for me.
function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    accountName = "vivekrgb97d"
    containerName = "test"
    fileName = "upload.txt"


    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/", credential= credential)

    containerClient = blobServiceClient.get_container_client(containerName)
    blobClient = containerClient.get_blob_client(fileName)

    content = blobClient.download_blob().readall().decode("utf-8")

    return func.HttpResponse(content)
    

azure-pipelines.yml:
trigger:
- main

variables:

  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

  functionAppName: 'pyfunc22aug'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  workingDirectory: '.'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.11'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.11 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'




When using DefaultAzureCredential make sure assign required role as per the action which needs to be performed.
For reference check this document

OUTPUT:



